# Get the latest date

Tags: arrays, date, powershell

I have an array that I call $data.

I want to get the earliest dates from the $data array for each host in my csv file. The user will input a host and it will find the earliest date it was modified.

```
    Hostname    LastModified
    HD           9/8/2012
    LOG          9/15/2004
    NETMAN       12/25/2004
    NETMAN       5/5/2015
    LOG          1/4/2013
    LOG          6/6/2011
```

So if they input LOG, I want it to give me the earliest date.

```
    Created on  9/15/2004
```

Code:

```
 $data= import-csv ".\Earliest Date Template.csv" 
 $Hostname=Read-Host "Please enter Host Name"
 $data | Foreach-Object {$_."Last Modified" = [DateTime]$_."Last Modified"; $_} | Group-Object Hostname| Foreach-Object {$_.Group | Sort-Object LastModified | Select-Object -First 1}
```

Comment: This can be done. Can you show us what you have tried so we can help guide you?

Comment: This is what I have so far.

$data= import-csv ".\Earliest Date Template.csv"
$hostname=Read-Host "Please enter Hostname"

$data | Foreach-Object {$_."Last Modified" = [DateTime]$_."Last Modified"; $_} | 
Group-Object Hostname| 
Foreach-Object {$_.Group | Sort-Object LastModified | Select-Object -First 1}

Comment: That is great to see. Can you add that to your question using the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35857562/edit) button below your post? Code looks terrible in comments.

Comment: ok that should be better

Comment: Your code looks ok. Do the right dates show up when you do this?  `$data | Foreach-Object {$_."Last Modified" = [DateTime]$_."Last Modified"; $_}` you don't really explain your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grouping them does seem like the way to go but you don't need to do that. Just sort the entire list by date then select the last option from the list (that matches the host name you are looking for).

```
$hostname = Read-Host "Please enter Hostname" 
$data | Sort-Object {[DateTime]$_."LastModified"} | Where-Object{$_.Hostname -eq $hostname} | Select -Last 1
```

You might need to do some user validation but something like this seems to work with your sample data:

```
Please enter Hostname: log

Hostname LastModified
-------- ------------
LOG      1/4/2013
```

If you then only want the date it would just be a matter of expanding the value from the result.

```
$data | 
    Sort-Object {[DateTime]$_."LastModified"} | 
    Where-Object{$_.Hostname -eq $hostname} | 
    Select -Last 1 -ExpandProperty LastModified
```